# How to send an email with attachment using typescript in protractor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

**I am using the below code for email sending with attachment using typescript in protractor.**

[image]

**Receiving the below error**

[image]

[image]

After implementing the SMTP,receiving the below error

Comment: did u check thread :https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8591#issuecomment-294713425

Comment: Here seems like not implemented properly

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/264/how-to-send-an-email-gmail-outlook-and-zoho-using-nodemailer-in-node-js

Comment: @xdeepakv Even though I have updated my code with reference to your second link, receiving the diff error. Attached the image in the question

Comment: do you run your tests locally? or in CI/CD?

Comment: @sergeyPleshakov I have executed locally

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I have Executed locally